# Cell position in TableView on MouseEvent

Tags: mouseevent, tableview, javafx-8

I'm trying to get the position of a cell in a TableView in JavaFX after a mouse event. I get the correct row value, but the column value is null. Any ideas why?

```
table.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            TablePosition tc = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
            System.err.println(tc.toString()); // I get the correct row, but the column value is null.
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to react to mouse clicks on individual cells in the table? If so, it's usually better to register the mouse handler with the `TableCell`s than with the `TableView` (which you can do by setting a cell factory).  The cell knows its current index and table column. (The answer to your actual question might be that you don't have cell selection enabled on the table's selection model, but you haven't really posted enough code to know if that is the case.)

Comment: Thanks @James_D! The answer was that I didn't have cell selection enabled. Easy as that!